# What is the length of the segment at angle $\alpha$ from a point on the diameter to the circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, power-of-the-point

In Proposition [III.7](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII7.html) (see also [modern version](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Relative_Lengths_of_Lines_Inside_Circle)), Euclid shows that in the diagram below $FA > FB > FC > FG > FE$.

Assuming $\angle CFE = \alpha$, what is the actual length of $FC$ (in terms of $FD$) on a unit circle?  I tried to determine this algebraically but was not able to (some attempts are [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+for+s%3A+s+sin+a+%3D+sqrt%281+-+%28u+%2B+s+cos+a%29%5E2%29), [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+for+d%3A+d+%3D+%281%2Fsqrt%282%29%29*%28sqrt%28u%5E2%28cos+2a+-+1%29%2B2%29+-+2u+cos+a%29%3B+u+%3D+1%2F2), and [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ngxlwm0fvn), abbreviating $u = FD$).

[image]

I also tried to solve geometrically using Power of the Point (again, letting $u = FD$ and $C'$ be the other intersection of $FC$ with the circle): $$(1+u)(1-u) = FC \cdot FC' \\ FC + FC' = ? $$ but could not express $CC'$ in terms of $\alpha$ (or anything else useful).

Comment: Can't be done. $\alpha$ is an exterior angle of the triangle $CDF$, so you can get the corresponding interior angle from that, but then you know only one side ($FD$) and one angle ($\pi-\alpha$). This is not enough information to determine any of the other sides (or indeed any of the other angles). For this to be solvable, you also need any of the following: 1) angle $CDF$ 2) segment $CD$ 3) both 1) and 2)

Comment: The size of the circle does not matter in this instance, only the quantities I specified

Comment: @H.sapiensrex But in a unit circle, $CD$ is of course 1!

Comment: Oh of course! I'm a dumbass lol. Pardon me; it's morning here and I'm still waking up... but yes, knowing $CD$, you can now use the law of sines to find $CF$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $u=DF, v=CF, \alpha = \angle CFE, \alpha' = \angle CFD, \beta = \angle CDF, \gamma = \angle DCF$, and noting that $CD = 1$ because it is a radius of the circle, we can use the law of sines to set up two equations of two unknowns:

$$\frac{\sin{\alpha'}}{1} = \frac{\sin{\beta}}{v} = \frac{\sin{\gamma}}{u}$$

Note that $\beta = \alpha - \gamma$ so:

$$\sin{\alpha'} = \frac{\sin{\alpha - \gamma}}{v} = \frac{\sin{\gamma}}{u}$$

Thus $\gamma = \arcsin{(u\sin{\alpha'})}$. Recognize that $\sin{(\alpha - \gamma)} = \sin{\alpha}\cos{\gamma} - \sin{\gamma}\cos{\alpha}$ so:

$$\sin{\alpha'} = \frac{\sin{\alpha}\cos{\gamma} - \cos{\alpha}\sin{\gamma}}{v}$$

Next we realize that $\cos{\gamma} = \sqrt{1 - u^2\sin{\alpha'}}$ and $\sin{\gamma} = u\sin{\alpha'}$ so we end up with:

$$\sin{\alpha'} = \frac{\sin{\alpha}\sqrt{1 - u^2\sin^2{\alpha'}} - u\cos{\alpha}\sin{\alpha'}}{v}$$

Which, solving for $v$ and simplifying, gives us:

$$v = CF = \sin{\alpha}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sin^2{\alpha'}} - u^2}-u\cos{\alpha}$$

The following plot compares the simulated distance CF as well as the calculated distance using the derived formula (setting $u=0.2$).

[Plot of calculated CF distance and simulated distance against $\alpha$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj1TJ.png)

The following Python code produced that plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = np.linspace(1e-5, np.pi-1e-5, 1000)
u = 0.2
point_F = np.array([u, 0])
point_C = np.array([np.array([1, 0])*np.cos(a) + np.array([0, 1])*np.sin(a) for a in alpha])
CF_simulated = np.array([np.linalg.norm(p_c - point_F) for p_c in point_C])
CF_calculated = np.sin(alpha)*np.sqrt(1/np.sin(np.pi - alpha)**2 - u**2) - u*np.cos(alpha)
plt.plot(alpha, CF_simulated)
plt.plot(alpha, CF_calculated)
plt.legend(['CF_simulated', 'CF_calculated'])
plt.xlabel(r'$\alpha$ (rad)')
plt.ylabel('distance CF')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The simulated distance is calculated by first calculating the point C for each alpha and then calculating its distance from F. I don't have the code anymore as I did it in powershell but the idea for calculating C for each alpha is (1, 0)*cos(alpha) + (0, 1)*sin(alpha) and the distance from F is the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: That is a bad plot. Give me a minute and I'll fix it. I'll update the answer as well.